# how to remove empty value in multiselect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

HI how to remove empty value in multi select, bellow my code

```
    $(document).on('blur','.select2-search__field', function(e) {
    var current_select = window.localStorage.getItem("current_select");
    console.log($(this).val());
    if (current_select) {
        if ($(this).val()) {
        $("#"+current_select).append('<option value="'+$(this).val()+'" selected>'+$(this).val()+'</option>');
        //$("#"+current_select).val($(this).val());
        $("#"+current_select).trigger("change");
        }
    }
 });
```

when I enter new values that value appended it is working , but same time one empty value automatically comes so how can i removed please help me

Output is :

```
<option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
<option value=" 12345" selected="selected"> 12345</option>
<option value=" abcd" selected="selected">abcd </option>
```

First value is empty, so how can I remove this.

Comment: the out put is  <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option> <option value=" 12345" selected="selected"> 12345</option><option value=" abcd" selected="selected">abcd </option>  first values empty so how can I removed

Comment: trim the value and check.

Comment: where I trim the value

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$('select option')
.filter(function() {
    return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
})
   .remove();
```

or

```
$("#select option[value=' ']").remove();
```

Comment: So there is no way to have select2 NOT CREATE this empty option first ???